# Import cannot be resolved (Junit)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I am trying to write unit tests for my project in `Maven` using `Eclipse` IDE on Windows.

I have imported `jUnit4` on build Path using `Eclipse` plugin.

```
(junit.jar under /path/to/eclipse/plugins/org.junit4.12.0.v201504281640).
```

I am able to import these. (weirdly)

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
```

But I have problem importing these

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Before;
```

Do I have to add another `JUnit` library or is there some other problem?

Note: There are no `JUnit` dependencies in `Maven`. I am importing `JUnit` jar directly in build path.

EDIT: I forgot to mention but I did use static for `junit.Assert`.

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.8.1 why do not use this ?

Comment: Why don't you use pom dependency for this??

Comment: for assertEquals, shouldn't it be import static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assertEquals isn't a class but a methods so you have to option :

import org.junit.Assert;

and calls Assert.assertEquals

or use :

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

and call : assertEquals